# 500 error when trying to post completed update to todo item (rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post

I'm trying to update my completed boolean on the index once the checkbox has been checked, unchecked, etc.

When I click on the checkbox I get a 'POST 500 MYURLHERE (Internal Server Error)' in the console log.

Can I get a fresh pair of eyes on this to point me in the right direction? I must be going wrong somewhere...

The error log (rails server)

```
Started POST "/todos/16/completed" for 80.193.7.142 at 2016-04-30 16:52:34 +0000
Cannot render console from 80.193.7.142! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by TodosController#completed as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"16"}
  Todo Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "todos".* FROM "todos" WHERE "todos"."slug" = ?  ORDER BY "todos"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["slug", "16"]]
  Todo Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "todos".* FROM "todos" WHERE "todos"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 16]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.1ms)  UPDATE "todos" SET "completed" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "todos"."id" = ?  [["completed", nil], ["updated_at", "2016-04-30 16:52:34.117248"], ["id", 1
6]]
   (64.1ms)  commit transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 78ms (ActiveRecord: 64.6ms)

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template todos/completed, application/completed with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, "application/ecmascript", "application/x-ecm
ascript", :html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, 
:zip, :web_console_v2], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/g9stuart4/recital/app/views"
  * "/home/g9stuart4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-4.0.0/app/views"
):
  actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/path_set.rb:46:in `find'
  actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:121:in `find'
  actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:18:in `find_template'
  actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:40:in `determine_template'
  actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:8:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
  actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
  actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
  /home/g9stuart4/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/benchmark.rb:303:in `realtime'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.5.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:815:in `call'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `block in call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  /home/g9stuart4/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /home/g9stuart4/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/g9stuart4/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /home/g9stuart4/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/missing_template.text.erb (0.3ms)
```

My Checkbox / Input (index.html.erb)

```
<%= check_box_tag 'todo[completed]', todo.id, todo.completed, data: { remote: true, url: url_for(controller: :todos, id: todo.id, action: :completed), method: "POST" }, id: todo.id %>
<%= label_tag todo.id, "COMPLETE", :class => 'strikethrough' %>
```

My Controller

```
  def completed
    if @todo.update_attributes(:completed => params[:completed])
      flash[:success] = "Wowzers."
    else
      flash[:error] = "Not so wowzers.."
    end
  end
```

My Routes

```
resources :todos do
    member do
      post 'completed'
    end 
  end
```

Any info is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error suggests, you don't have a `todos/create.html` template in your views folder.

By default, controller actions will render a template of the same name in the folder matching the name of the controller resource (plural). I think what you want to do here is render/redirect appropriately within your `create` action:

```
def completed
    if @todo.update_attributes(:completed => params[:completed])
      flash[:success] = "Wowzers."
      redirect_to action: :show   # Redirect to the #show action so we can show our updated TODO.
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Not so wowzers.."  # Since we're not redirecting, we use `flash.now` instead of flash.
      render :new  # Rerender the form because we have an error
    end
  end
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you for the detailed response. I have no error anymore but upon refresh after updating the todo it is no longer ticked. Do you have any idea why that might be?